# Is there any ways to track user in app purchase without application login

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I'm creating an app that use `IN-App Purchase` and I want to track the user Purchase on my server so user doesn't have to redownload the same purchase. But my client want that to do without the login module in app.
I don't mean that do purchase without the iTune/app-store login. I means I don't want to make user login in application.
So does iTune/app-store provide us some special user related unique identifier to know that this is the same user which downloaded this purchase before.

**EXAMPLE**

Suppose if user have downloaded English Language Pack from the iPhone and when he try to download same Language Pack from the iPad with same Apple id than our server can know that this is the same user and provide him his all previous purchase(which is English Language Pack downloaded in iPhone and already done payment using in-app purchase) on the iPad also.

**This is how i think i can do this (but this logic only be successful if apple provide some unique id for user)**
So if apple provide some unique identifier on the purchase to my app than i will store it on my server when user download the English language pack on iPhone and when he tries to download same language pack in iPad than apple again provide me his unique identifier and i will compare this id on my server and know that i have to let user download this language pack

So Does apple provide UniqueID for user or we can find the Users Apple Id(not password)?

Comment: @Vinzzz now is it okay?

Comment: I remembered I could do the edit myself, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need to do your purchases trough the In-App Purchase, Apple is not going to allow you to use your own service.

Summarizing, you cannot sell anything on your app that is not trough Apple.

After your edit:

If you want that a user has the same product in iPhone and iPad, you have to indentify that user somehow, let say with his email. then when the user buys one thing, store that email on the server, and give the product for that user for free in the iPad.

You have to store something if you want to recognize that user in iPhone and iPad.

Comment: No, sorry if i have not represent correctlly. But i want to use the Apple in-app purchase

Comment: I just want that track the user purchase just by the login of the app store. Not by creating login module in app and or using the facebook.

Comment: Sorry english is not my first language so hard to explain.

Comment: Can you put an example?

Comment: Checkout the example please.

Comment: Thats the problem as i said that my client want to manage all without the inserting any personal detail of user in the app.

Comment: So then there's no way of recognizing a user that uses an iPad and an iPhone

Comment: So thats why i am depending on the in-app purchase if apple provide any unique id for the user than i will send that id to my server and keep the track of the user.

Comment: No, Apple wont provide you that

Comment: Ok so only option is `user must have to login`.:(

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is '[restore purchases](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH8-SW9)' functionality in StoreKit.
Note that not all in-app purchases can be restored this way.
But I think that in your case - permanent functionality purchase - you can use iOS 7 new [SKReceiptRefreshRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKReceiptRefreshRequest_ClassRef/SKReceiptRefreshRequest.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SKReceiptRefreshRequest) class.

If you have to support older versions of iOS, use `[SKPaymentQueue restoreCompletedTransactions]`([SKPaymentQueue API reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPaymentQueue/restoreCompletedTransactions)).

**EDIT** : 'purchases' that appear in the receipt depend on product type, [see tables at bottom of this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Products.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH2-SW5)